# Why does the internet in my house stop working whenever my brother opens up his macbook when he's visiting?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, macbook

Every time my brother visits my house and opens up his computer, the internet no longer works. Even hard wired devices are no longer able to connect. I'm fairly sure this is a router issue because I never have to restart the modem. I just turn the router on and off and everything is up and running again in a minute or two. But once he opens his computer again it happens again. Without fail. I read on-line somewhere a while back that it may be possible for a router to assign it's own ip address to a computer, but I can't find that article anymore. Could this be the problem? And how do I fix it? Do i need to assign him a static ip address through his own network preferences on his macbook? The router? Both? Thank you in advance for any ideas that can help me. 
using a netgear router, he's got a 2012 macbook pro. He connects to my guest network, though I don't see how that could be part of the problem. Ok. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a concrete answer because we can only guess without further analysis. So I'll concentrate on the first step of a possible analysis here and eventually amend this answer, depending on the outcome.

First, please note down your configuration when the internet access is working without problems, i.e. turn off your brother's laptop, reboot your machine and your router, *verify that internet access **is working***, and then:

- Open a command prompt with administrative privileges, i.e. open the start menu, type `cmd`, right-click the entry "Command Prompt" and select "Run as administrator" from the context menu.
- In the command window that opens, type `ipconfig /all` and post the output (of course, format it as code, and please don't post it as a comment, but edit your question instead). Hint: You can copy-and-paste the output directly from the command window, or you can redirect the output in a text file like that: `ipconfig /all > config.txt`.

Secondly, turn on your brother's laptop and *verify that internet access **is not working*** any more. Then repeat the two steps shown above (or only the second one if the elevated command window is still open). Again, post the output you have got in the second step.

We then can have a look at it and perhaps find the problem or proceed with the next step.

Comment: `ipconfig` does not require admin permissions.

Comment: You are right - thanks for the hint. Actually, I've been unsure about it and didn't have the time to test :-) Furthermore, the next steps (depending on his results) might require them.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My brother won't be back in town till next week, but when he's here I'll run the steps you outlined and report back. Thanks again for your help

Comment: And to be sure, when you say open a command window, you mean my macs terminal?

Comment: @RyanDeMont For some reason, I assumed it was *your brother* who had the MacBook pro (since you have written this in your question and have tagged the question accordingly), while I assumed that *you* were on Windows. The latter assumption is obviously wrong, so my answer is not helpful for you. Sorry for not having understood the situation  ... I never had a MAC and thus really have no clue what the command lines would be in the terminal; perhaps something Unix-ish like `ifconfig -a` or `ip show addr`.